# How to measure frequency of aperiodic signal in simulink when you are getting that signal through arduino?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, simulink

Actually i want to measure frequency of a signal that i am getting thorugh arduino . I am getting almost correct voltage value near 220V that is value of our national grid and frequency in our national grid is 50 Hz

.One approach according to my understanding is that if signal is periodic, we can change simulation time from deafult value 10 to 1, and then from graph shown in scope , we see number of signal cycles in 1 second. This approch seems reasoanble for periodic signals but what about mesauring frequency of a peridoic signals?

I have also attached snapshots

**Main block diagram snap**
[image]

**Ac volatage subsystem is open up in below fig**
[image]

**When i set simulation time to inf, i get below graph**
[image]

**and when i get When i set simulation time to 1, i get below graph**
[image]

Comment: What is the frequency of an aperiodic signal? Are you looking for something like an FFT, which will give you some idea of the signal's power spectrum?

Comment: Please check updated question.